# Finding perimeter knowing area of right angle triangle and ratio of sides

Tags: triangles, area

Hi I am stuck on this question (GCSE extended maths) I can sort of get to the correct answer but I am not clear why. There is no clear explanation (or at all) how to do this in any texts I have looked at. The question looks like a curve ball to me, but I am sure I am missing something:

> The area of a right-angled triangle is $51.2cm^{2}.$
>
> If the two perpendicular sides are in the ratio $1:1.6,$ find the lengths of all three sides of the triangle.

Comment: Please include the problem and your attempt to solve the problem in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then

- $\frac12 ab = 51.2$
- $\frac{a}b=\frac{1}{1.6}$

$$\implies b=1.6 a \implies0.8a^2=51.2\implies a=8 \quad b=12.8 \quad c=\sqrt{8^2+12.8^2}$$

Comment: @Hancho Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of sides is 1:1.6

or lengths $x$ and $1.6x$

Area $=  \frac 12 bh\\ 0.8 x^2 = 51.2\\x^2=64\\x = 8$

Two of the sides then are $8$ and $12.8$

The 3rd side you can find using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Note that I gave only a hint to let the OP was solved in detail by himself.